# Java GUI not appearing after implementing socket methods

Tags: java, swing, sockets, user-interface

I get no errors in my code. The code works fine as long as the code within the start method, that i created, is commented out. I am unsure why this is happening. I have tried moving the code around but that does not solve the issue. Why is the code within the start method preventing the GUI from showing on screen?

```
package my.IPMessenger;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
/**
 *
 * 
 */
public class IPMessengerGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    static ServerSocket SC;
    static Socket socket;
    static BufferedReader in;
    static DataOutputStream out;
    static char[] c;
    static String text;
    static String iP;
    static Socket sock2;
    static BufferedReader in2;
    static DataOutputStream out2;
    static InetAddress address;

    /**
     * Creates new form IPMessengerGUI
     */
    public IPMessengerGUI() throws IOException {
        start();
        initComponents();
        jTextArea1.setLineWrap(true);
        jTextArea2.setLineWrap(true);
//        SC = new ServerSocket(6850);
//  socket = SC.accept();
//  socket.setKeepAlive(true);
//  in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
//  out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
//  c = new char[1000];
//        in2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock2.getInputStream()));
//        out2 = new DataOutputStream(sock2.getOutputStream());
//        search();
    }
    private void start() throws IOException{
        SC = new ServerSocket(6850);
    socket = SC.accept();
    socket.setKeepAlive(true);
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    c = new char[1000];
        in2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock2.getInputStream()));
        out2 = new DataOutputStream(sock2.getOutputStream());
        search();   
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jScrollPane3 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea2 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jScrollPane1);

        jTextArea2.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea2.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane3.setViewportView(jTextArea2);

        jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("jButton2");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jMenu1.setText("File");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        jMenu2.setText("Edit");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(91, 91, 91)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 250, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane3))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(97, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 53, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton2))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jButton2))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 38, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void search() throws IOException{

        while(true){
            if(in.ready()){
                in.read(c);
             for(int count = 0; count < c.length ; count++){
                text += c[count]; 
             }  
            jTextArea2.append(text);
            }
        }
    }

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        jTextArea2.append(" " + jTextArea1.getText());

        try {

            out.writeChars(jTextArea1.getText());
        } catch (NullPointerException|IOException ex) {

        }
        jTextArea1.setText(null);
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        String ip =( JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "please enter a valid IP address:"));
        int convert = Integer.parseInt(ip);
        byte[] bytes = BigInteger.valueOf(convert).toByteArray();
        try {
             address = InetAddress.getByAddress(bytes);
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(IPMessengerGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {
            sock2 = new Socket(address,6850);
            sock2.setKeepAlive(true);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(IPMessengerGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(IPMessengerGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(IPMessengerGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(IPMessengerGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(IPMessengerGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                try {

                    new IPMessengerGUI().setVisible(true);

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(IPMessengerGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            }

        });

    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me that you are never actually getting to the GUI portion of your code. You may want to use some multi-threading here, as that is what you seem to be aiming for. In your constructor, you are calling your start method--all fine and good so far--and it seems to execute as you would expect it. **HOWEVER**, when you call `search()` at the end of `start()`, it enters an infinite loop (the parameter being `true`). Your loop logic is preventing a return from `search()`, thereby a return to `start()`, and then to the constructor.
I hope this helps, and best of luck to you!

Comment: I have removed the search method. After removing the method, the GUI still will not show.

Comment: Have you tried connecting anything to the sockets? Sockets generally get their own thread, so that their connection wait doesn't hog the Stack's daemon. If you use Eclipse, set some way-points to each of the lines in your `start()` method, and see where the program hangs when you hit the debugger button.

Comment: The GUI stops showing at this line: socket = SC.accept();

Comment: Right, exactly what I said in my other comment. Please feel free to read up on how sockets work. The most important part of a socket, is that when you call the `accept()` method on said socket, it will sit there and wait forever to accept something. The way around this, is to assign a separate `Thread` object to each socket, so that your daemon can continue to run, even as your socket waits. That can cause problems for some; so, an alternate way to do that, would be to simply have the `accept()` method be the last thing that you call--that way, it will wait after everything else is drawn.

Comment: The invokeLater(...) method causes the code to execute on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). The EDT is responsible for painting the GUI. Since the socket blocks on the accept() method the GUI can never repaint itself. I would suggest you should use a `SwingWorker`. The SwingWorker is a separate Thread that allows you to `publish` results as they are received. Again this is important because the GUI should be updated on the EDT. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information and examples.